# Find and replace string in a file using 'sed' or 'awk'

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Let's say I have the following input file:

```
yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.X9HCJG.1 yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.Z2HCJG.1 100.000 100 
yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.X9HCJG.1 yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.AUEM0K.1 94.144  72  
yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.X9HCJG.1 yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.H5SFBV.1 93.156  72  
yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.X9HCJG.1 yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.L5AFBV.1 62.169  58  
yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.X9HCJG.1 yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.90R752.1 92.188  64  
yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.X9HCJG.1 yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.MP1IPV.1 90.278  72
```

I need this for output file

```
yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.X9HCJG.+v1.0 yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.Z2HCJG.+v1.0 100.000 100 
yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.90R752.+v1.0 yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.AUEM7K.+v1.0 94.144  72  
yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.X9HCJG.+v1.0 yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.H5SFBV.+v1.0 93.156  72  
yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.L5AFBV.+v1.0 yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.L5AFBV.+v1.0 62.169  58  
yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.X9HCJG.+v1.0 yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.90R752.+v1.0 92.1.188 64 
yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.AUEM7K.+v1.0 yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.MP1IPV.+v1.0 90.278  72
```

I have `yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.**othercode**.1` string common in all file but i just want replace **1** with **+v1.0** at the end of string like `yhara.runner.mng1.nna1.**othercode**.+v1.0`
I have tried with `sed` and `awk` commadline to find and replace like below

```
awk '{print $1}' demo.txt | sed -i -e 's/.1/+v1.0/g'
awk '{print $2}' demo.txt | sed -i -e 's/.1/+v1.0/g'
```

but thats response nothing

thanks
best regards

Comment: It would help if you could show exactly what you've tried and where it failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple Perl solution would be:

```
perl -p -e 's/\.1 /+v1.0 /g' your_file.txt > replaced.txt
```

You can also use `sed -e` instead of `perl -p -e`.

This replaces an occurrence of `.1`  (with a space) with the string `+v1.0`  (again, with a space).

You can use the `-i` option (for both Perl and sed) to replace the file in-place, but note that for `sed` this only works under Linux, not macOS.

Comment: thanks i tried your command but  your_file.txt == replaced.txt..there is no change in replaced.txt file..

Comment: surely after .1 there is TAB not space...now what sould i do??

Comment: thanks for answer but there is tab in my case... so sed -e 's/\.1\t/.+v1.0 /g' your_file.txt > replaced.txt

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your command is that `sed -i` replaces in the file, but the `awk` outputs the captured strings. You can solve it with @slhck's solution to simply replace every `.1` with `.+1.0`, but to be a little more flexible and robust (for example for any `.1`  in the 3rd or 4rth column), I would probably solve it like this (warning: POSIX regex fast approaching):

```bash
sed -iE 's/([^[:space:]]+)([0-9])[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+)([0-9])/\1\+v\2.0\3\+v\4.0/' input.txt
```

It looks complicated, but it's not when we break it down:

1. `[^[:space:]]+[0-9]` first match any character that's **not** whitespace ending in a number (`\s` might also work, but that's not always supported).
2. then we group each of them so we can reference them later `([^[:space:]]+)([0-9])`
3. After that is any number of whitespace characters `[[:space:]]+`
4. Followed by the same match groups like in step 2

For the replacement part it's:

1. `\1` group 1
2. print `+v`
3. `\2` group 2
4. print `.0`
5. Then the same thing with groups 3 and 4

If it's really always the number `1` that should be replaced, you can also replace `[0-9]` with simply `1` and if it's always a `tab` character you can try replacing `[[:space:]]` with `\t`. That would make it a lot simpler, but also less flexible.